# Matrix of an orthogonal projector

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the matrix, which in standard base of $\mathbb{R}^3$ belongs to the orthogonal projector onto a line $2x=2y=z$.

The vector of the line is $(1,1,2)$. Orthogonal subspace to this vector is a plane with base vectors $(2,0,-1)$ and $(0,2,-1)$.

How do I proceed?

Comment: You have a base in which the matrix is simple. Now apply a change-of-base transformation to the simple matrix.

Comment: If $(2,0,-1)$,$(0,2,-1)$ and $(1,1,2)$ are vectors of a nonstandard base, then the matrix of my projector is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, is this correct?

Comment: No, the projection is onto the line, not along it, so it's identity matrix minus yours.

Comment: Thank you, that part I didn't understand.

Comment: The result is then $\frac{1}{12}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 4\\ 
2 & 2 & 4\\ 
4 & 4 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the matrix of a linear transformation $L : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is given in the standard basis by $$\pmatrix{ L(e_1) & L(e_2) & L(e_3) },$$ where $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are the standard basis vectors. Thus you need to find the projections of these vectors onto the line you were given.